# How can I use the REPLACE function to change these two words using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and SSMS. I have two particular values I am trying to replace:

- 'South Manchester' to 'King's Landing'
- 'Manchester' to 'Highgarden'

I have the following syntax:

```
UPDATE Correspondence SET [Name] =
REPLACE(REPLACE([Name], 'Manchester', 'Highgarden') , 'South Manchester',' King’s Landing')
```

I end up with names like 'SouthHigarden'. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a condition with a `WHERE` statement. Also, I noticed you might have the quotation marks not used properly.

Try this:

```
UPDATE Correspondence SET [Name] = "King’s Landing"
WHERE [NAME] = "South Manchester"

UPDATE Correspondence SET [Name] = "Highgarden"
WHERE [NAME] = "Manchester"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Out of curiosity can REPLACE be used with a where clause?.

Comment: Yes, you could use it in the `WHERE` clause. like this example: `WHERE ( Column_Name LIKE @last_name + '%' )`

Comment: "I noticed you might have the quotation marks not used properly": sql server uses single quotes for literal string, double quotes are for object identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

You need only to order the updates right, so that Manchester alone is te last to update

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Correspondence (name varchar(100))
> GO
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Correspondence VALUES ('South Manchester' ),('Manchester' )
> GO
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE Correspondence SET [Name] =
> REPLACE(REPLACE([Name], 'South Manchester',' King’s Landing'), 'Manchester', 'Highgarden') 
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Correspondence
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | name              |
> | :---------------- |
> |  King’s Landing |
> | Highgarden        |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a6ad4808eeffd2c7ebb688c6187f270b)*

Comment: Clever. I like it.